# Sending an image through $http.post

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to catch a file using `PHP` and `AngularJS`. However, I cannot send the file successfully using `AngularJS`.

HTML

```
<input type="file" ng-model="image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().sendFile(this);">
```

Angular function

```
$scope.sendFile = function(image) {

    var postData = {
        image: image.files[0]
    };

    $http.post($rootScope.root + '/test/image', postData).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

As of now, the `image.files[0]` is an `array` of information about the file. Location, size and so on.

How do I pass the actual file?

Comment: if want full browser support...suggest using uploader plugin

Comment: Appending @charlie: yes something like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. View templates are also written in angular and it supports many browsers. And btw, where is your <form></form> ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can access the image via its source, convert it to base64 and then pass it simply as a parameter